# Handling search with querySelectorAll, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, dom, search

Wanting to create simple search function that loops through items in a table and only displays the ones that match the text in the input field. I've retrieved each element I want to search for from the DOM using a class but not sure what's missing.

This is the search Input

```html
<div class="flex items-center py-4 shadow">
        <svg
          onClick="myFunction()"
          class="h-6 w-6 text-gray-500 mx-6"
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          fill="none"
          viewBox="0 0 24 24"
          stroke="currentColor"
        >
          <path
            stroke-linecap="round"
            stroke-linejoin="round"
            stroke-width="2"
            d="M21 21l-6-6m2-5a7 7 0 11-14 0 7 7 0 0114 0z"
          />
        </svg>
        <input
          class="w-full p-2 text-gray-400 focus:text-gray-800 text-base outline-none"
          id="search"
          type="text"
          placeholder="Search"
        />
      </div>
```

This is an example of one row in the HTML :

```html
<tbody class="bg-white divide-y divide-gray-200">
   <tr>
      <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-no-wrap">
         <div class="flex items-center">
              <div class="flex-shrink-0 h-10 w-10">
                   <img class="h-10 w-10 rounded" src="img/product-1.jpg" alt="" />
               </div>
               <div class="ml-4">
                 <div class="text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 searchable" > 
                    De'Longhi EC685M Dedica Deluxe Espresso
                 </div>
                </div>
              </div>
           </td>
           <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-no-wrap">
              <div class="text-sm leading-5 text-gray-900">
                  $800.00
               </div>
           </td>
           <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-no-wrap">
              <span class="px-2 inline-flex text-xs leading-5 font-semibold rounded-full bg-green-100 text-green-800">
                   + 8%
               </span>
            </td>
            <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-no-wrap text-sm leading-5 text-gray-500">
                 ...
             </td>
             <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-no-wrap text-right text-sm leading-5 font-medium">
                <a href="#" class="text-indigo-600 hover:text-blue-500 pr-4">
                   Inspect
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-900">
                   Delete
                </a>
        </td>
   </tr>                     
  </tbody>
```

```js
// Handle Search
const searchBar = document.querySelector("#search");
searchBar.addEventListener("keyup", function (e) {
  // Search Term to lower case
  const term = e.target.value.toLowerCase();
  // Look for Item
  const item = document.querySelectorAll(".searchable");
  // Loop through each item to see if text matches
  Array.from(item).forEach(function (i) {
    const title = item.textContent;
    if (title.toLowerCase().indexOf(term) != -1) {
      i.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      i.style.display = "none";
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: please share your HTML too

Comment: Yes sorry, I've added it.

Comment: Your HTML doesn't contain an element with the id "search". That's causing the error.

Comment: Hi Lonnie, the search id is in the first html section with the input tag.

Answer (score 0):

The **querySelector** you are using with #search but there is no id with **search** in your code. So the **searchBar** is null and you are trying to add eventListener to a null element.

You are trying to access the wrong element in your foreach loop of your js file

```
// Handle Search
const searchBar = document.querySelector("#search");
searchBar.addEventListener("keyup", function (e) {
  // Search Term to lower case
  const term = e.target.value.toLowerCase();
  // Look for Item
  const item = document.querySelectorAll(".searchable");
  // Loop through each item to see if text matches
  Array.from(item).forEach(function (i) {
    // const title = item.textContent; Here it should not be **item** 
    //it should be the element of the loop in your case it is i
     const title = i.textContent;
    if (title.toLowerCase().indexOf(term) != -1) {
      i.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      i.style.display = "none";
    }
  });
});
```

I hope it should work fine now

Comment: Hi Mithirdi, thanks for taking the time to read through this. I've added my input html field in my question.

Comment: @Simon Please check the code snippet i have added once

Answer (score 0):

There's an issue with querySelector, you can create an array of NodeList by this way:

```js
const searchBar = document.querySelector("#search");
searchBar.addEventListener("keyup", function (e) {

  let term = e.target.value.toLowerCase();
  let items = [...document.querySelectorAll(".searchable")];
  
  for(let item of items){
    if(item.textContent === term){
        console.log(item);
    }
  }

});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="search"/>

<p class="searchable">a</p>
<p class="searchable">s</p>
<p class="searchable">d</p>
<p class="searchable">f</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that solved the console bugs but I cant get the if statement to output item in the console. Only the else is outputing the data in console.